# How to handle a confusing question?

Tags: support, questions, edits

In this question

> [git diff between current workspace and master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46463116/6501141)

the questioner confuses a lot of git terms and ultimately is not clear on his real question as a result.

After some back and forths in comments, some answers being posted, and some back and forths on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463501/6501141), I finally realized the confusion point, and updated my answer.

But at this point, I feel like the question should be fixed to make it clear what he is asking, so that people looking for an answer don't need to wade through everything before realizing whether this Q&A matches their question or not, etc.

So I made an edit, but I wasn't sure how to edit it without essentially rewriting his question in a way that the comments and answers would make any sense.  So I added a section at the end of his question with a note stating this was a clarification of the original answer, and a short explanation (he was not making any changes to the local repo, only wanting the diff between the prior master commit and the new one after pulling).

This seemed like a good compromise, but was it?

A few hours later I rechecked the post, and my edit had been removed/deleted, and a new edit was in place that basically left his question completely intact, and still completely confusing. Is this the correct solution?

**How should situations like this be handled when you eventually realize that the intent of the questioner was not clear and he has helped in comments to clarify, but editing directly would really change the core wording, etc. and make the answers and comments look out of place?**

Comment: Editing a question after it is answered is pretty tricky.  I'd guesstimate that at least half of all questions would become irrelevant if they were stated properly.  That has to be higher for [git].  It just isn't unusual, the site tries to provide Q+A to everybody that is equally confused.  Fwiw, your proposed edit was rejected so never visible, looks like the reviewer thought it changed too much.  Sweeping changes are almost always rejected.

Comment: The question you linked already looks perfectly fine to me. I see that some fluff has been removed in edits but nothing substantial has changed since it was posted. Other than that: sure it uses some bad terminology and muddles the concepts, but that's because the poster had those confusions. Fixing it up would make it *less* useful to future visitors in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my edit will rewrite a question, I typically leave a comment with a
[shorthand link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)
asking the original author to `[edit]` the question him- or her-self:

> It sounds like your question is really asking *Topic A*, and has nothing to do with *Topic B*.
>   Please `[edit]` your question to include the details from your last three comments.
>   You should probably remove the tangent about *Red Herring* while you're at it, since it's just a distraction.

This makes the edit less likely to happen, but it's generally better if drastic changes come from the source.
Also, it can help really new users learn what's expected of them.
(Many have no idea that they can edit their questions.)

If serious answers have already been posted, I'm less likely to suggest such changes.
It's possible that they understood the question better than I did.
("Try this"
shots in the dark don't count;
if the Time Cube guy posted on Stack Overflow, within two minutes he'd get an answer saying
"use a regex".)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, especially the considerations on how it helps out new users - that's one of my concerns.